# ORMs : Map multiple tables into a single object

Tags: c#, database, orm

I do have a database with multiple tables that represent different parts of the same DD object:

```
DD(ID*, name) (the name and ID of the DD)
DD_DATA(ID*, DD_ID(foreign_key), MONTH, YEAR, VALUE) (its annual data)
DD_MODEL(ID*, DD_ID(foreign_key), X_value, Y_value, Z_value) (its mathematical model, using a fk since it's a one-to-many relationship)
```

Since it's a huge application, I went to using ORMs, but I'm new at this. Currently I'm benchmarking and trying a lot of them, so I didn't settle yet with which one to use.

**My question**: Can (at least one) ORM be set to map these tables into a single object and translate the DD_DATA and DD_MODEL tables into some kind of arrays (or objects) inside one single DD class? Or do I have to do this by hand (I mean, creating a DD object and then extracting all its data by hand).

Comment: Which ORM?.....

Comment: Any of them, I know some are more abstract than others (like Dapper and EF, so I'd like to know if it can be done, and which ORMs can do it). Since I'm new at this, I am willing to learn whatever can do it.

Comment: Dapper will just map any query to objects, so you can select mixed fields from multiple tables at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dapper, the mapping is done based on the results of whatever query you run.  Your query can join many database tables - as long as the resulting column names match up to the object properties that you are mapping, you will be fine.